# Tips for a more beautiful layout

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, align

Has anybody some tips for me to improve to look of the following:
(Especially the division of the formula)

[image]

And the code:

```
Aus Lemma \ref{yog2.2} folgt:
\begin{align*}
    \betr{D_x\bet{n}{k}{\mathcal{P}_n}} &= \betr{\bet{n}{k}{\mathcal{P}_n\cup \{x\}} - \bet{n}{k}{\mathcal{P}_n}}\\
    &\leq \sum_{j=k}^{k+1} S_j(\mathcal{P}_n,r_n;\{x\})\\
    &\leq [\mathcal{P}_n(B_{r_n}(x))]^k + [\mathcal{P}_n(B_{r_n}(x))]^{k+1}\\
    &\leq 2 [\mathcal{P}_n(B_{r_n}(x))]^{k+1}
\end{align*}
und analog \( \betr{D_x\bet{n}{k}{\mathcal{X}_n}} \leq 2 [\mathcal{X}_n(B_{r_n}(x))]^{k+1} \).
```

This is just an example part of my document, but I´m unhappy with its look. I also can not quite determine the reason of what I don´t like, but maybe you have some advice. I appreciate it!

Those are my own-defined commands:

```
\newcommand{\betr}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert} %absolute value
\newcommand{\bet}[3]{\beta^{{#1}}_{{#2}}({#3})} %betti-number
```

PS: I´m using lmodern.

Comment: As always on the site you are much much more likely to get help if you provide a full (but minimal) example instead of sniplets. Here we have to guess even to be able you use your code and thus many will pass on your question.

Comment: Besides the missing period at the end it looks fine.

Comment: Unrelated: your definition os `\betr` is not a good idea, autoscaling is asking for trouble (try `\betr{\sum_i}` it looks terrible). I suggest using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools` (disclamer I wrote the macro).

Comment: Okay thank you! I change my definition of `\betr`.

Comment: Plus  with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` the macro will have an autoscaling variant, it can be handy, just not a good idea to let it be the default.

Comment: Why is it not a good idea?

Comment: Autoscaling often end up being wrong, encompassing more than it needs to. So scaling by hand is often better (it takes experience to know when to pick which size) and then leaving the autoscaling to when appropriate.

Comment: Try this example: `$ \left(b\right) \left(\hat{b}\right) $` the first the of scaling () does nothing, so the `\left` and `\right` just makes it harder to read. In the second example, why does the fences need to encompass the hat? I edit fences using the following rule: It should be clear to the reader what is being fenced in. But not to such an extent that the fences take focus (hence the `\betr{\sum_i}` example). As an addendum: If the fences are 'far away' from something tall, they doen't need to encompass it to clearly mark that it is fenced in.

Comment: Okay I guess I understand. Thank you for your patient answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this layout?

```
\documentclass[german]{article}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm} 

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\betr}{\lvert}{\rvert} %absolute value
\newcommand{\bet}[3]{\beta^{{#1}}_{{#2}}({#3})} %betti-number

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Aus Lemma \ref{yog2.2} folgt:
\begin{flalign*}
 & & \betr{D_x\bet{n}{k}{\mathcal{P}_n}} &=\betr{\bet{n}{k}{\mathcal{P}_n\cup \{x\}} - \bet{n}{k}{\mathcal{P}_n}}
    \leq \smash[t]{\sum_{j=k}^{k+1}} S_j(\mathcal{P}_n,r_n;\{x\}) &
    \\
     & & & \leq [\mathcal{P}_n(B_{r_n}(x))]^k + [\mathcal{P}_n(B_{r_n}(x))]^{k+1} \\
    & & &\leq 2 [\mathcal{P}_n(B_{r_n}(x))]^{k+1} \\[2ex]
 & \text{{und analog}} &
\betr{D_x\bet{n}{k}{\mathcal{X}_n}} & \leq 2 [\mathcal{X}_n(B_{r_n}(x))]^{k+1} & \qedhere
\end{flalign*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]